# Simulation Nodes: How to make this quite simple curve effect?

Tags: simulation-nodes

I'm trying to learn the simulation nodes but just can't wrap my head around it.

This effect probably could be done with the regular geometry nodes, but I think it would be so much simpler with simulation nodes, since you could blast away a new strand per frame.

So, how to create this following effect in simulation nodes?

[image]

More of the effect is seen in here, but still not much:
https://youtu.be/7tY_eaRAFj4?t=47

If I was to describe the effect, there is this curvy but still pretty straight central line, and with each frame or so a new strand is generated from it, which acts entirely independently, as if randomly selecting from a set of rotation vectors per frame, which makes really nice movement for it.

How would you approach this with simulation nodes?

Comment: Quick guess: this is Houdini Curl Noise .. not directly accessible in Blender, but [derivable](https://entagma.com/geometry-node-simulation-advect-by-curl-noise/)

Comment: @RobinBetts Thank you! Excellent addition to the information. I shall explore this curl noise for this project :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with this node tree:

[image]

[image]

you will get this as a good starting point:

[image]

Comment: The node tree looks quite complex to rebuild... I would quote one of your favourite sentences: please upload the file :D

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann: i "normally" do it like this: if the OP provides a blend file, i often provide one in the answer as well. If the OP doesn't - i "normally" don't provide it too. I think that's pretty fair, because the OP didn't make it easy for us because we had to rebuild everything on our own. Every pro like you can build it anyway ;)

Comment: and "complex" is relative. Did you see Erindale's node trees? mine is easy in comparison ;)

Comment: Oh yes, I've seen Erindale's ;) It's not like I cannot build it, it's just looking back and forth to finally get all the different nodes the same as in the picture is annoying work... and then maybe troubleshooting if it does not work which one of those is incorrect. It's something different if I would follow along with a tutorial and build it step by step. To be fair to the OP, if one has no idea how to build it, what kind of file should be provided? A single object with a blank nodetree? ;) But anyway, great result.

Comment: thanks! ;) well, even if it is just a curve animated with a trim curve and maybe some more curves added - would be start and showing the good will - then i would have provided my blend file as well. Maybe i am a bit weird - but i like this "giving and taking" - that's why i like to answer here - because i got a lot of great amazing answers here and learned a lot here.

Comment: "just a curve animated with a trim curve" - I guess I'm just too disillusioned and sarcastic by now, I actually don't expect much anymore here when I read some questions. I sometimes wonder how people managed to get to the point where they are stuck when they don't understand the basic commands and tools. But that's just my pessimistic view of the (user) world. :D

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann: you made my day :D i even think worse sometimes - i strongly believe that some people are just to lazy to do it - they maybe even could - but they save time by letting this do but some fanatics here who do it for free by just writing 2 sentences and adding a link by OP ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146636/discussion-between-gordon-brinkmann-and-chris).

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make this to my liking with quite a simple setup after all. Thanks for @RobinBetts for informing about the Entagma's Curl Noise setup.

[image]

Nodes:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice result! Entagma is worth following, even if you don't use Houdini.